How to handle dynamic session IDs in JMeter for T24 load testing?
I'm performing load testing on T24 using JMeter and encountering an error message: "SECURITY VIOLATION (Code: SV-06)". I discovered that this error occurs because there is an issue with the Sign off transaction, which fails. As a result, when the next user tries to log in, they receive the SV-06 error code.
I believe the solution involves making the request parameters dynamic. I need to capture certain values from the response (e.g., compScreen) using regex and pass them as variables in subsequent requests.
Below is a screenshot of my current HTTP request configuration in JMeter:
What I need help with:
Capturing dynamic values (such as session IDs and compScreen) from the response of a login request using regex.
Passing these captured values as variables in subsequent requests to avoid session-related issues.
(https://i.sstatic.net/8MpGRJ7T.png)]
(https://i.sstatic.net/wM9MLCY8.png)]
(https://i.sstatic.net/lQWnwfw9.png)
Thank you!
Could someone guide me through the steps to capture these values with regex and how to pass them as dynamic variables in JMeter?
Thank you!

If you're asking for our help in getting a dynamic parameter from the response to the "login request" you're supposed to provide this response (at least partial, with these compScreen parameter and whatever else you need) and preferably in form of text, not the screenshot.
Without it we won't be able to come up with proper Regular Expression Extractor configuration. So far I can only suggest getting familiarized with Regular Expressions chapter of JMeter User Manual
You can try using Correlation Recorder Plugin, it has Auto-Correlation feature which can capture dynamic elements for you.
